# Was this set with TeX?

Tags: fonts

This maybe seems like a weird question, but since I started using TeX/LaTeX I see more and more things in "real life" that seem to be set with it. E.g. the train timetables here in Germany are set with some kind of TeX usually and you can clearly recognize the computer-modern-fontface. Now, after quite a long time, I looked something up in my Brockhaus (German encyclopedia) from 1980 and, though, I am no expert, I believe it was set with TeX too. The font looks pretty much like CM, the equations look a lot like CM and so on.

[image]

So, does anyone know what the Brockhaus was set with in the 80's? Or does anyone recognize what it was if it wasn't some kind of TeX?

Comment: I am not sure if this is really typeset with TeX, although it should be technically possible since the development started in 1977. But I doubt that it has been used by publishing houses in this time.

Comment: The math font is not italic, the spacing around binary relations (\ge) is not correct, so it certainly does not look like TeX output.

Comment: And the font is surely not Computer Modern, rather some Times variant.

Comment: This font is not CM, the details differ.  In CM the thinnest curves are exactly on the top and bottom, in this font they're on the bottom right, top left (like Times).  Also, TeX was released in 1978, so in 1980 it was likely much less popular (computers were much less popular...)

Comment: IMHO this was not TeX. See the lower index on the sum. Too ugly!!

Comment: The first ‘real’ version of TeX was TeX82 (aka TeX 2.0), which was a thorough reworking of TeX78 (or TeX 1.0); in 1980 it was probably available no font for it other than ‘Almost Modern’ (the preliminary version of Computer Modern). @barbarabeeton could be more precise about this.

Comment: The font used is nothing like Computer Modern (or Modern in general) it looks like some Helvetica-like and Times-like fonts to my untrained eye.

Comment: Looks like Times, which means it’s likely typeset with Monotype’s “four line” math system, the state-of-the art before TeX. See http://typophile.com/node/71679 (though the link is down at the momenet).

Answer (score 2):

Certainly most authorative is http://www.brockhaus.de/kontakt/index.php.

However, to suggestions that it cannot be TeX (not CM, too early, bad spacing in inequality) I can add the following:

1. The height of `\circ` in definition of Quadrat.
2. The shape of triangle in definitions.
3. The place of `i` under sum in quadratische Form.
4. The spacing around `=`'s.
5. The retort-like shape in Quadratsäure.
6. The structural formula, evidently obtained manually (see the endings of the lines).